# Wix Bootstrapper failing to resolve .Net Framework

Tags: wix

I need my installer to install the .Net framework as a prerequisite and according to what Ive found online this is the way to do it:

```
<Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef  Id="NetFx45Web" />
     <MsiPackage SourceFile="... my msi.." />
</Chain>
```

However, I get this compilation error:

> Error 53  Unresolved reference to symbol 'ChainPackageGroup:NetFx45Web'
>   in section
>   'Bundle:SetupBootstrapper'.   C:\Source\skystoredesktop\SetupBootstrapper\Bundle.wxs  8   1   SetupBootstrapper

What is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a reference to WixNetFxExtension to your bundle project

this can be done on the light command line thus:

```
light Bundle.wixobj -ext WixNetFxExtension
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you also know how to do this for Silverlight as I asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255962/wix-silverlight-prerequisite

Answer (score 0):

To add the reference through Visual Studio 2019:

1. Right Click on "Wix Bootstrapper Project > Reference"
2. Get into Wix Toolset bin folder and select the DLL by getting into below folder:
   *

> C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixNetFxExtension.dll

Now the build should work without any error