# Wix Silverlight prerequisite

Tags: silverlight, wix

I have a Wix bootstrapper project that installs .Net framework from the web if needed.
No I would like to do the same for Silverlight.
Ideally from the web but if I have to I will bundle it.

So how do I add Silverlight as a prerequisite?

Comment: Ok, It was quite simple to bundle it just using a ExePackage with the Silverlight.exe installer. However, I read somewhere that when you download the .exe there is some javascript on the Microsoft website that determines if you are to download the 32 or 64 bit version. Now I would really like to have this installer downloaded on demand so it will be downloaded if needed. I found both the DownloadUrl attribute and the RemotePayload child element but I cant  get it to work. Any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

```
  <ExePackage Id="sl"
              Compressed="no"
              DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156"  
              SourceFile="C:\Users\mah67\Downloads\silverlight.exe"
              Cache="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Protocol="netfx4"
              Vital="yes"
              InstallCommand="/q" 
              Permanent="yes"
              Description="Silverlight Runtime"  
              DisplayName="Silverlight" 
              SuppressSignatureVerification="yes" >
```

The source file attribute is apparently needed so Wix can extract info about the file at compile time. Compressed="no" means that it should not be bundled at compile time. RemotePayload is used when the file isnt available at the time of building the package.